# proportional resize jquery

Tags: jquery, resize

I am having trouble with image resizing. Here is the code:

```
  function resize() {
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var winWidth = $(window).width();
var divHeight = winHeight * .9;
var divWidth = winWidth * .7;
var marginT = -1 * (divHeight / 2);
var marginL = -1 * (divWidth / 2);

if (winHeight > 300) {
  $('#picture-box').height(divHeight);
  $('#picture-box').css("margin-top", marginT);
}
if (winWidth > 300) {
  $('#picture-box').width(divWidth);
  $('#picture-box').css("margin-left", marginL);
}

var divPos = $('#picture-box').offset();
$('#close').css('top','50%');
$('#close').css('margin-top',marginT);
$('#close').css('left',((divPos.left + divWidth) - 20)+'px');

var w = $('#main-image').width();
var h = $('#main-image').height();
var p = (divWidth-w<divHeight-h)?(divWidth/w):(divHeight/h);
var nw = Math.round(w * p) * .9;
var nh =  Math.round(h * p) * .9;
$('#main-image').width((nw>1)? nw : 1);
$('#main-image').height((nw>1)? nh : 1);
var imgMarginT = (divHeight - nh) / 2;
var imgMarginL = (divWidth - nw) / 2;
$('#main-image').css("margin-left", imgMarginL);
$('#main-image').css("margin-top", imgMarginT);
$('#close').css('position','fixed');
$('#close').css('z-index','101');

$('#tshirt-button').css('left',divPos.left);

$('#memory-button').css('left',(divPos.left + divWidth) - 130);

$('#left-arrow').css('left',divPos.left + 25);
$('#right-arrow').css('left',(divPos.left + divWidth) - 75); }

function triggerRightArrow() {
if (quiltType == 'tshirt') {
  tshirtIndex++;
  if (tshirtIndex > MAX_TSHIRT_INDEX)
    tshirtIndex = 1;

  $('#picture-box').html('<img id = "main-image" src = "images/quilts/tshirt_'+tshirtIndex+'.jpg" />').then(resize(), resize());
}
else {
  memoryIndex++;
  if (memoryIndex > MAX_MEMORY_INDEX)
    memoryIndex = 1;

  $('#picture-box').html('<img id = "main-image" src = "images/quilts/memory_'+memoryIndex+'.jpg" />').then(resize(), resize());
} }

function triggerLeftArrow() {
if (quiltType == 'tshirt') {
  tshirtIndex--;
  if (tshirtIndex < 1)
    tshirtIndex = MAX_TSHIRT_INDEX;

  $('#picture-box').html('<img id = "main-image" src = "images/quilts/tshirt_'+tshirtIndex+'.jpg" />').then(resize(), resize());
  //resize();
}
else {
  memoryIndex--;
  if (memoryIndex < 1)
    memoryIndex = MAX_MEMORY_INDEX;

  $('#picture-box').html('<img id = "main-image" src = "images/quilts/memory_'+memoryIndex+'.jpg" />').then(resize(), resize());
  //resize();
} }
```

My problem is that when the triggerRightArrow function is called, the picture loads properly, but is resized wrong. When I call triggerRightArrow again, then call triggerLeftArrow, the image is properly resized. This explanation may be confusing, so here is the page to demonstratehttp://creationsbyanna.x10.mx/quilts.html

If anyone could tell me how to get the pictures to resize properly the first time they load, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: im not sure if this is the problem $('#main-image').height((nw>1)? nh : 1); i guess it should be (nh>1) rather than (nw>1)?

Comment: I tried that. Still the same results

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it working by loading the pictures in the cache on the load of the page. I'm still not sure why the pictures only resize properly when they're loaded in the cache, but this is the only solution I've found so far. Here's what I put in the $(init) method:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= MAX_TSHIRT_INDEX; i++) {
  heavyImage = new Image(); 
  heavyImage.src = 'images/quilts/tshirt_' + i + '.jpg';
}

for (var i = 1; i <= MAX_MEMORY_INDEX; i++) {
  heavyImage = new Image(); 
  heavyImage.src = 'images/quilts/memory_' + i + '.jpg';
}
```